# How to check-if or wait-for message processing completion?

Tags: java, spring-integration, jmockit

I want to perform JUnit test for application using Spring-Integration framework. What I want to test is:

- If the message was properly processed by service activator connected to the channel I am sending
- If there was a proper message error handling procedure invoked in case of any errors

I am using JMocikt to verify if expected methods are called. I start the test by calling `send` on a message channel.

The problem is: *How do I wait for message processing to end?* Spring integration spawns several threads and sending on message channel returns immediately. What I have already tried is:

- Using `IntegrationMBeanExporter.stopActiveComponents(false, 0)` - it fails because of thread interruption
- Trying to chain service activators (first: the actual call, second: notification of completion) - it fails because the service activator under test returns `null` in which case, it cannot be chained. Also, I do not like it, because I have to alter SI configuration under test.

Any clues?

Please do not comment on not performing real unit, but integration testing etc. I know what I am doing.

Answer (score 4):

The most common technique used in test cases is to replace the final channel with a `QueueChannel`, inject it into the test case and perform `assertNotNull(finalChannel.receive(5000)`. You can even test the received message to verify it contains the expected data.

It's a bit more tricky when you use asynchronous processing and the final service doesn't return a result (or `null`). In that case, you can make the final channel a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` and, in your test case, add a second subscriber (with a higher `order` attribute), such as a `<bridge/>` to a `QueueChannel`, and then `receive()` the result as above.

Comment: Does order attribute make execution sequential?

Comment: The parse order is used by default; I tend to prefer to add an explicit order attribute to each subscriber 1, 2, 3 etc. It doesn't hurt if there's only one subscriber, and it makes the intent clear. They will be called sequentially as long as the `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` doesn't have a multi-threaded task executor. By default, each subscriber will be called sequentially on the thread that sends to the channel.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, thanks. One problem I still have is the fact, that error-channel is (as far as I know) used only with asynchronous calls. This introduces big change to testing procedure.

Comment: No; the `error-channel` is used for synchronous flows too. We should move this to a chat - SO is not intended as a discussion board.